# Image not showing in document

Tags: overleaf, includegraphics

I am trying to include an image in an article in Overleaf, my source code is shown below,

```latex
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=80mm]{Appendix/Currents/C1.08current.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

When compiling the document all the PDF shows is 'Figure 6.5' so it seems to be recognising something but isn't displaying the image, I'm not getting a white box as some users have mentioned

Comment: Hello there! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. I don't know what could cause this. But you can reach me on Overleaf support email address and we try to see what's going on there. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.

Comment: @yo' two dots.   latex presumably gave you an error that the extension `08current.png` is not known.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, a silly mistake on my part but the issue was cause by the image being called 'C1.08current.png' changed the file name to 'C1_08current.png' and the image was included successfully